# OpenSSL with FIPS cross compiling for iOS armv7

Tags: ios, openssl, cross-compiling, fips

I cross compiled the FIPS for armv7 using the instructions from
http://opensslfoundation.com/testing/validation-2.0/platforms/ios/

I am having difficulties cross compiling openssl dependency on fips.

I am getting following error in terminal.

```
/usr/local/ssl/fips-2.0/bin/fipsld: line 185: ./openssl: Bad CPU type in executable
make[2]: *** [link_app.] Error 1
make[1]: *** [openssl] Error 2
make: *** [build_apps] Error 1
```

This is because the openssl executable under the "/apps" folder is of architecture armv7.
Since I am cross compiling openssl, I need only the libssl and libcrypto with architecture armv7, other intermediate executables should build with i386 architecture.

Any help with setting up the environment variables is appreciated.

Comment: Any clue please? I had the same problem compiling OpenSSL with FIPS

Comment: @Krypton did you over come this error? If so, how?

Comment: I did, but I do not remember how, very sorry...

Answer (score 2):

The [OpenSSL FIPS User Guide 2.0](http://openssl.org/docs/fips/UserGuide-2.0.pdf) has a comprehensive example of building the FIPS Object Module and FIPS Capable Library. It also offers a sample iOS program to test your build against. See Appendix E on p. 122.

From the looks of it (due to `link_app` error), you did not set your environment properly with `setenv-ios-11.sh`. That caused your build attempt to build the executables (which should not be built in this configuration).

Comment: Perhaps the guide and setenv worked at one point, but they most certainly do not now!

Comment: @Peter - Yeah, its hard to say... I know `setenv-ios-11.sh` is out of date. Its does not pick up the iOS 7 SDKs (see around line 45). I tired to provide an updated script that included error checking, but no one acted on it (I sent it multiple times, and eventually gave up).

Comment: I just found what I think is your lib, https://github.com/noloader/openssl-1.0.1i-ios .That might help others with this question!

Comment: @Peter - yes, that's mine. I don't advertise it very much to avoid the site's self promotion rules. But its not FIPS. I think it has the updated script use. The script can be used for FIPS, too.

Comment: Any clue please? I had the same problem compiling OpenSSL with FIPS